# Trying to Add Background Photo in HTML file on Github Repository

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I've been using a Github repository of HTML code I've been working on to show up for a Google Domain I recently purchased (wescar.org). I can't seem to get a background photo to show up that is in the same directory as my index.html file. https://github.com/thefrontbottoms247/thefrontbottoms247.github.io

I've tried adding <body background = "math.jpg"></body> underneath of my headers. math.jpg is in the same directory as the index.html file in my repository.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a background image you don't use `background: "image filepath";` instead you use `background` with `url()` as the value. Ex. `background: url(some_file_path.png);`